# Data-Object Aliases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm looking to alias an object -- mainly tables -- in SQL Server. There is the concept of ["Alias" in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-ver15), but this refers to at the Server/Instance level and I am looking to persistently alias db objects.

As an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyDB].[MySchema].[MySalesTables]
```

Instead being able to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales
```

I know I can temporarily alias a table/field by doing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyDB].[MySchema].[MySalesTables] AS sales
```

But I'm wondering if there is a management layer in SQL Server (or even SSMS) where I can just add aliases to my most common table names so that I can refer to them more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It's called a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). eg

```
CREATE SYNONYM MyEmployee   
FOR AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee;
```

Comment: perfect, yes that was what I was looking for -- thank you. Out of curiosity, what if I am user A with my database and that database has a synonym "Employee", and you are User B and you have another database that has a synonym "Employee" and you share your database with me. What happens if I type in "Employee" for a table name? Or are synonyms resolved at the database (or cluster?) level.

Comment: A synonym is an object inside a particular database and schema.  The same name resolution rules apply for a synonym as a table or a view.